# Logic error on standard deviation

Tags: java

I've written this Java program for homework , but it is producing logic errors , and I'm not at all sure why. Here's my code:
I also don't know why public class StndredDev { decided to remove itself from the code block, but its easy enough to read even so.
First time posting, couldn't find a logic-error tag.

Edit: problem solved, I would post my finished code but this was a homework assignment so maby it should be removed? I'm new here so I don't know the policy on posting completed homework assignments

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StndredDev {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        final int numOfDigits=10;

        // declare double array
        double [] numbers = new double [numOfDigits];

        // promt user
        System.out.println("Enter ten numbers : ");
        double k = 0;
        double j = 0;
        double deviation = 0;

        //Begin computing mean
        for (int i=0; i < numOfDigits; i++) {
            numbers[i] = input.nextDouble();
            k += numbers[i];
        }
        double mean= k/numOfDigits;

        // Display mean
        System.out.printf("The mean is %.2f", mean);

        //Begin computing standard deviation, I'm at a loss as to why this is still giving me logic errors.
        for(int m=0; m < numOfDigits; m++) {
            deviation = Math.pow((numbers[m]-=mean),2);
            j += deviation;
        }
        double stndrdDeviation = j/numOfDigits;
        double standardDeviation = Math.sqrt(stndrdDeviation);

        //Display Standard Deviation
        System.out.printf("the standard deviation is: %.6f", standardDeviation);
    }
}
```

Comment: `" I also don't know why public class StndredDev { decided to remove itself from the code block,... "` -- always read the help files on how to post in a site before posting. It will explain that all code should be indented 4 spaces and how to do this easily and automatically. I've done it for you this time, but next time, again, read the help files. That's what they're for.

Comment: What's a "logic error"?

Comment: Please tell us what testing you've done that shows that your code is not working correctly. What results did you expect, and what did you get?

Comment: You need to better explain what kind of error you're getting.

Comment: We ended up going over it in class today , everything was explained, the error was in the formula. thank you for the quick responses and I'll be sure to remember to be more specific in the future, and show output

Answer (score 1):

1. `deviation = Math.pow((numbers[m]-=mean),2);` - this line doesn't make sense to me. What you want is `deviation = Math.pow(numbers[m] - mean, 2);` I assume this is the error you mention.
2. Don't define so many variables you don't need. Reuse them. For example,

   ```
   double stdev = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < numOfDigits; i++){
       stdev += Math.pow(numbers[i] - mean, 2);
   }
   stdev = stdev/numOfDigits;
   stdev = Math.sqrt(stdev);
   ```

   Also, it seems you assume that for each loop you need a separate variable. You don't. Both `i` and `m` are local and live only within those loops independently, there's nothing wrong to name both of them `i` because they do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I was only getting an error in the output, the problem was in the formula but it was covered in my class today.